# LIBSVM Data Preparation: Excel data to LIBSVM format

Tags: libsvm

I want to study how to perform LIBSVM for regression and I'm currently stuck in preparing my data. Currently I have this form of data in .csv and .xlsx format and I want to convert it into libsvm data format.

[image: Current Data]

So far, I understand that the data should be in this format so that it can be used in LIBSVM:

[image: LIBSVM format]

Based on what I read, for regression, "label" is the target value which can be any real number.

I am doing a electric load prediction study. Can anyone tell me what  it is? And finally, how should I organized my columns and rows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The LIBSVM data format is given by:

> <label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ...
> ...
> ...

As you can see, this forms a matrix [(IndexCount + 1) columns, LineCount rows]. More precisely a **sparse matrix**. If you specify a value for *each* `index`, you have a *dense* matrix, but if you only specify a few indices like `<label> <5:value> <8:value>`, only the indices `5` and `8` and of course `label` will have a custom value, all other values are set to `0`. This is just for notational simplicity or to save space, since datasets can be huge.

For the meanig of the tags, I cite the [ReadMe file](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r94100/libsvm-2.8/README):

> <label> is the target value of the training data. For classification,
>   it should be an integer which identifies a class (multi-class
>   classification is supported). For regression, it's any real
>   number. For one-class SVM, it's not used so can be any number. 
>   is an integer starting from 1, <value> is a real number. The indices
>   must be in an ascending order.

As you can see, the `label` is the data you want to predict. The `index` marks a **feature** of your data and its `value`. A feature is simply an indicator to associate or correlate your target value with, so a better prediction can be made.

**Totally Fictional** story time: Gabriel Luna (a totally fictional character) wants to predict his energy consumption for the next few days. He found out, that the outside temperature from the day before is a good indicator for that, so he selects `Temperature` with index `1` as *feature*. **Important:** Indices always start at one, zero can sometimes cause strange LIBSVM behaviour. Then, he surprisingly notices, that the day of the week (Monday to Sunday or `0` to `6`) also affects his load, so he selects it as a second *feature* with index `2`. A matrix row for LIBSVM now has the following format:

`<myLoad_Value> <1:outsideTemperatureFromYesterday_Value> <2:dayOfTheWeek_Value>`

Gabriel Luna (he is Batman at night) now captures these data over a few weeks, which could look something like this (load in kWh, temperature in °C, day as mentioned above):

`0.72 1:25 2:0`
`0.65 1:21 2:1`
`0.68 2:29 2:2`
`...`

Notice, that we could leave out `2:0`, because of the *sparse matrix* format. This would be your training data to train a LIBSVM model. Then, we predict the load of *tomorrow* as follows. You know the temperature of today, let us say `23`°C and today is Tuesday, which is `1`, so tomorrow is `2`. So, this is the line or vector to use with the model:

`0 1:23 2:2`

Here, you can set the `<label>` value arbitrarily. It will be overwritten with the predicted value. I hope this helps.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot for this very comprehensive explanation.. i was perfectly clueless about the data format for libsvm but this really helped me understand it.. thank you so much!

Comment: One of the best explanations found on the web. What prominence does libSVM format hold when I try to build a model using SVM? Can't I just scale the data and run it through the algorithm to get a trained model?

Comment: @thatguy, I think I'm missing something... is the index-feature correspondence kept in a different file? It seems strange to me that only arbitrary indexes are used in the libsvm file...